# How to run an app in batch file?

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, cmd.exe

Having such super simple *batch* file for `Win 10`

```
@ECHO OFF
start "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

When I launch it a *command* window titled `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` appears instead of just launching the `firefox`.

What's wrong with the script?

Comment: @John Ok, thx that worked but I'm REALLY curious WHY my solution doesn't work?

Comment: @John As far as I've read the `start` help `(start /?`) in the answer You've provided the string in quotes is just the window title, not a patch to program...

Comment: @John You're a little wrong friend, read the answer I've accepted - this i just the title for the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if the first parameter to `START` is a quoted string, it will assume that it is the intended title. If you need to pass a quoted string for the executable because of spaces in the pathname, put an empty string `""` as the first parameter to `START`:

```
START "" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
```

*Editorial comment: This is stupid. If it were properly designed, `start` would require a switch (e.g., `/T`) to signal the window title.*

Comment: You're right, but how to se that tile thing? When i type `START "Abc" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"` there is no `Abc` in the opened window...

Comment: @Mulligan - It will be the title of the CMD window that's opened, not the FireFox window. If the CMD window closes immediately after Firefox is launched (which is normal for non-console programs), there won't be a window for the title to apply to.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thx.